# Why template class not working properly for double?

Tags: c++, templates, template-classes

I have the following code:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
template <class T> class Stack
{
private:
    T a[1001];
    int i=0,j;
public:
    void pop(void)
    {
        a[i-1]=0.0;
        a[i-1]='\0';
    }
    void push(T &x)
    {
        a[i++]=x;
    }
    void push(const char &x)
    {
        a[i++]=x;
    }
    void top(void)
    {
        cout<<a[i-1];
    }
};
int main()
{
    Stack<char>s1;
    s1.push('a');
    s1.push('b');
    s1.top();
    s1.pop();
    cout<<"\n";

    Stack<int>s2;
    s2.push(10);
    s2.push(20);
    s2.top();
    s2.pop();
    cout<<"\n";

    Stack<double>s3;
    s3.push(5.50);
    s3.push(7.50);
    s3.top();
    s3.pop();
    cout<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
b
20
7
```

why it's showing 7 for double instead of 7.5 ?
when i explicitly specialize for double and don't use reference operator it works well.

```
void push(double x)
{
    a[i++]=x;
}
```

this gives correct output for double.
but, when i do this it gives error.

```
void push(T x)
{
    a[i++]=x;
}
void push(const char &x)
{
    a[i++]=x;
}
```

how to fix this ?
how to show correct output for double ?

Comment: Lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues.

Comment: Also, you're not "specializing" anything.

Comment: OT, but your `pop` function actually doesn't decrement `i`

Comment: @MattMcNabb i know, it doesn't decrement i. i just used that to show output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
s3.push(7.50);
```

it resolves to the overload

```
void push(const char &x)
{
    a[i++]=x;
}
```

since `7.5` cannot be converted to `double&`, which will be needed to use:

```
void push(T &x)
{
    a[i++]=x;
}
```

As a result, you get the truncated value of `7` in the stack.

If you want the call to resolve to`void push(T &x)`, create a variable and use the variable in the call.

```
double x = 7.5;
s3.push(x);
```

Comment: @KhairulBasar When the argument type is `const&`, the input value is truncated in a temporary memory location and the temporary memory location is passed to the function.

Comment: Another possible fix is for `push` to take `x` by value or by const reference

Comment: thank you. but if i simply use     void push(char &x)    it works well for all...is it okay or it will create bug ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to R Sahu's answer. In C++11, a new type of reference called the **r-value reference** has been introduced. R-value references are used to refer to **unnamed** variables, which in this case is what 7.5 is.

What R Sahu meant by "`7.5` cannot be converted to `double&`" is that an **l-value reference**, which is your `double&`, **cannot be bound to an r-value**, which is your `7.5`.

L-value references `T&` can only be bound to l-values. R-value references `T&&` can only be bound to r-values. **Read-only** l-value references `const T&` however, can be bound to l-value or r-value, read-only or not. Therefore, function overload resolution will resolve to `push(const char& x)` because it takes in a **read-only l-value reference**.

Thank you for reading.